# How to add CSRF Token to a dynamically generated form by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csrf, django-csrf

```
 function populateMatches(id) {
 var url = "/get_matches/?s=" + id;
 $.get(url, function(response) {
     $container = $('.match-list-container');
     var i = 0;

     if (response.length > 0) {
         $container.html("");
         $container.append("<h5>Matches</h5>");
         $.each(response,function(){ 
             $container.append($("<h4>").text(response[i].match_percentile));
             $container.append($("<h6>").text("%"));
             $container.append($("<p>").text(response[i].match.content));
             $container.append('<form action="#" method="POST" id="match-info-form"><input type="checkbox" id="approve">Approve<input type="checkbox" id="discard">Discard<input type="checkbox" id="skip">Skip<br><input type="submit" id="savebutton" value="Save">');
             i++;
         })
     } else {
         $container.html("");
         $container.append("<h5>No Match Found</h5>");
     }
 });
}
```

**populateMatches** is function which is being called on a **click event**.
The server sends a response which contains **variable number of objects** depending on the div being clicked.

So if 'n' objects are present in the response, i need to **create n forms dynamically** and hence can't create the form in a static html file.

But how do I add the CSRF Token to the form in my javascript file.?

I know one can simply write **{% csrf_token %}** in a html template form, but how to overcome this problem when form is being generated dynamically.

P.S. I don't want to exclude csrf verification

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply store the CSRF token as a meta tag?  Then grab and insert on response?

See: [Is it a good practice to store the csrf token in meta tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680409/is-it-a-good-practice-to-store-the-csrf-token-in-meta-tag)